# Connecting to API's through Tor

Tags: php, api, nginx, tor

So I'm developing a site that needs to periodically update the value of bitcoin using nginx and php. I want to connect to the API using Tor so the IP of my site isnt shared or leaked. I'm kind of new to using tor and only used the browser before and I havent used SOCKS before. I'm trying to teach myself but most of the tutorials I find on google are using VPS's to act as a VPN. I'm developing the site on my localhost and want to be able to test it from my machine. How would I use PHP and configure my application to connect to APIs such as blockchain.info using a Tor connection?

Comment: This isn't really the site for tutorials and guides, it's a Question and Answer site. When you have a specific question about something, like part of your API/Tor code doesn't work, we can answer and help why

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of a PHP library called [TorUtils](https://github.com/dapphp/TorUtils) which includes [curl](http://php.net/curl) wrapper class that ensures requests go through Tor's SOCKS proxy and does not leak IP or DNS requests made through it outside of Tor.  I'd suggest you take a look at that.

You will first need to install, configure, and run a Tor daemon locally, which I won't go into here.  You can generally find a release listed [here](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-unix.html.en) and install it using your OS's package manager.

Once Tor is up and running, by default it will listen for SOCKS connections on port 9050.  The following code assumes Tor is running on localhost and listening for SOCKS on 9050.

To start, install TorUtils in your project with composer:

```
composer require dapphp/torutils
```

To use it is as easy as:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

// configure a TorCurlWrapper to proxy through Tor at 127.0.0.1:9050
$tch = new \Dapphp\TorUtils\TorCurlWrapper('127.0.0.1', 9050);

// set curl options as usual
$tch->setopt(CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0');
$tch->setopt(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

try {
    // issue a GET request; throws an \Exception if the request fails for any reason
    $tch->httpGet('https://blockchain.info/ticker');

    // get the response body from the last request
    $response = $tch->getResponseBody();
    $response = $tch->getResponseBody();
    $data     = json_decode($response, true);

    echo "1 BTC equals {$data['USD']['15m']} USD\n";

    $tch->httpGet('https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/BTCUSD');
    $response = $tch->getResponseBody();
    $data     = json_decode($response, true);

    echo "BitcoinAverage ask rate is 1 BTC = {$data['ask']}\n";


} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    echo sprintf("Request to %s failed with error %d: %s\n",
        $tch->getInfo()['url'],
        $ex->getCode(),
        $ex->getMessage());

}
```

Check out the related examples [here](https://github.com/dapphp/TorUtils/blob/master/examples/CurlWrapper.php) and [here](https://github.com/dapphp/TorUtils/blob/master/examples/CurlCountry.php).

This class does little more but ensure that you safely use curl through a local Tor instance, and it makes sure your curl and PHP versions are high enough that you can resolve DNS names over Tor, and make requests fail if they do not go through the Tor proxy.  In addition, it abstracts requests and responses from curl a little bit so it's easier to detect failures and extract headers and response data from your requests.

If you have questions or suggestions, feel free to ask.

Comment: what happens if tor network goes down, i mean your no more connected to tor network ? thanks

Comment: An exception is thrown.  Either that it can't connect to the proxy or the request timed out or failed.